# Use onclick() return value later in HTML

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to implement a simple webpage for testing purposes.

I have this so far:

In HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<p id="message"> 1st Message </a><br>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="changeMessage()">
```

`changeMessage()` which is located in main.js, returns a string. ("2nd Message")

As soon as I click this button, I want to get the return value from "changeMessage" and change the value of the `<p id="message">` to the returned value, which is "2nd Message"

Is this possible? I tried using `innerHTML` property but couldn't figure out how to use the returned value.

Comment: Post your code and what you have tried.

Comment: Why not just change the value of the <p id="message"> from within the changeMessage function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `changeMessage` doesn't sound like it should actually return a value or at least it shouldn't be a side-effect free method. Make sure to name your functions in a way that reflect what they do.

If you keep inline handlers as in your current code, you could do something like:

```
function changeMessage(message) {
    document.getElementById('message').textContent = message;
}

<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="changeMessage('2nd Message')">
```

With that small little change, you just made your API more flexible and expressive.

However, this relies on many bad practices, such as the need for global variables. Modularity, testability and scalability is out of scope of this answer, but please at least have a look at [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) which is a better alternative to inline handlers.

Comment: Thank you! Passing a parameter would actually help me.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

```
function changeMessage() {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML="2nd Message";
}
```